# NTPD fails to sync

Tags: ntpd

I'm transferring from one server to another.  Identical configuration, newer hardware, same data center.  The new machine CAN speak NTP:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -d ntp.jentfoo.com
Password:
24 Aug 14:50:59 ntpdate[10935]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Sun Aug 24 17:40:33 UTC 2014 (1)
Looking for host ntp.jentfoo.com and service ntp
host found : stripes.jentfoo.com
transmit(173.203.211.73)
receive(173.203.211.73)
transmit(173.203.211.73)
receive(173.203.211.73)
transmit(173.203.211.73)
receive(173.203.211.73)
transmit(173.203.211.73)
receive(173.203.211.73)
server 173.203.211.73, port 123
stratum 2, precision -20, leap 00, trust 000
refid [173.203.211.73], delay 0.04141, dispersion 0.00014
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    d7a4aec6.c2942e94  Sun, Aug 24 2014 14:34:46.760
originate timestamp: d7a4b299.ef951806  Sun, Aug 24 2014 14:51:05.935
transmit timestamp:  d7a4b29a.0400cdfd  Sun, Aug 24 2014 14:51:06.015
filter delay:  0.04141  0.04160  0.04147  0.04152
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: -0.08754 -0.08769 -0.08770 -0.08774
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.04141, dispersion 0.00014
offset -0.087543
24 Aug 14:51:06 ntpdate[10935]: adjust time server 173.203.211.73 offset -0.087543 sec
```

So there's no firewall issue.  But no matter how long I leave it running, the ntpd server never synchronizes with its peers:

```
$ ntpq 127.0.0.1
ntpq> pe
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 andromeda.cs.pu .INIT.          16 -    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ns.nts.umn.edu  .INIT.          16 -    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 stan.greyware.c .INIT.          16 -    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 stripes.jentfoo .INIT.          16 -    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
ntpq> as

ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 18223  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  2 18224  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  3 18225  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
  4 18226  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
ntpq> rv
associd=0 status=c012 leap_alarm, sync_unspec, 1 event, freq_set,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Sun Aug 24 17:40:33 UTC 2014 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/3.15.5-hardened-r2", leap=11,
stratum=16, precision=-23, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=355.605, refid=INIT,
reftime=00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 19:00:00.000,
clock=d7a510c6.0be8b4ee  Sun, Aug 24 2014 21:32:54.046, peer=0, tc=3,
mintc=4, offset=0.000, frequency=0.000, sys_jitter=0.000,
clk_jitter=0.000, clk_wander=0.000
ntpq> rv 18226
associd=18226 status=8011 conf, sel_reject, 1 event, mobilize,
srcadr=stripes.jentfoo.com, srcport=123, dstadr=0.0.0.0, dstport=0,
leap=11, stratum=16, precision=-23, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=0.000,
refid=INIT, reftime=00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 19:00:00.000,
rec=00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 19:00:00.000, reach=000,
unreach=34, hmode=3, pmode=0, hpoll=10, ppoll=10, headway=0,
flash=1600 peer_stratum, peer_dist, peer_unreach, keyid=0, offset=0.000,
delay=0.000, dispersion=15937.500, jitter=0.000,
filtdelay=     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00,
filtoffset=    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00,
filtdisp=   16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0 16000.0
```

And I can't figure out why.  The old server is using the exact same configuration, and it works fine.  I don't know what to do.

Update: ntpd has been running overnight and:

```
2014-08-24 14:57:46.244875500 Starting ntpd ...
2014-08-24 14:57:46.246304500 Finished Parsing!!
... normal startup status ...
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871674500 receive: at 975 0.0.0.0<-212.1.209.194 mode 3 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871699500 transmit: at 975 0.0.0.0->212.1.209.194 mode 4 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871700500 receive: at 1117 0.0.0.0<-212.1.209.194 mode 3 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871700500 transmit: at 1117 0.0.0.0->212.1.209.194 mode 4 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871700500 receive: at 1300 0.0.0.0<-198.23.230.118 mode 3 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871701500 transmit: at 1300 0.0.0.0->198.23.230.118 mode 4 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871701500 receive: at 2115 0.0.0.0<-66.172.12.144 mode 3 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871725500 transmit: at 2115 0.0.0.0->66.172.12.144 mode 4 len 48
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871725500 auth_agekeys: at 4096 keys 1 expired 0
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871725500 auth_agekeys: at 8192 keys 1 expired 0
2014-08-25 01:24:53.871726500 auth_agekeys: at 12288 keys 1 expired 0
...  more of the same ...
```

It does appear to be transmitting/recieving.  All the `ntpq` output is identical except `rv 18226` answers `unreach=69` now.

Comment: Which server is the new one? stripes answered stratum 2 above.

Comment: Any errors in syslog or the boot log? Maybe the new system isn't being granted access to the Ethernet soon enough after booting and ntpd is giving up?

Comment: All of the above is from the new new server.  No booting involved, still launching by hand long after boot.  And no, I cannot find any relevant errors in any logs either.

Comment: Why did you snip some stuff from the log and replace with "normal startup status"? It's not working and you are not sure why it's not working, therefore it's tough to use the word normal. More importantly can you post your ntp.conf file? That is usually helpful in these situations.